# Refresh MS Access Form/Query Based On Combobox Value

Tags: ms-access, vba, criteria, ms-access-2010

Pretty simple explanation. I have a table with 10 entries, 5 entries with the year 2010 and 5 entries with 2011 in a column.

In the query I have, I use Like *2010 to filter out all entries equal 2010 and display onl those records.

On my form, I have combobox being populated with each unique year (from a different table). So my combobox values are 2010 and 2011.

Is it possible, when I select say 2011, I trim the right 4 characters and use as my Like criteria to refresh and requery the form, all done within VBA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refer to the value of a control in a query run from within an Access session, as long as the form which contains that control is open.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
WHERE date_field_as_text Like "*" & Forms!YourForm!YourCombo;
```

So perhaps you can use a similar query as your form's record source, and do `Me.Requery` in the combo box's after update event.

If that's not close enough to what you want, please give us more information about the data types of the fields involved.  Adding brief samples of the table data to your question could also help; please make it clear whether the "date" fields are text or Date/Time.

Comment: I think this might be what I'm looking for...referencing the table within VBA and requery. If this doesn't help, I'll update my original post.

Comment: HAHA...I'm stuck...I'm still fairly new to coding SQL but where do I add the code you posted to?

Comment: Ok yeah I found the SQL part...told you I was fairly new. Can I trim the right 4 character of my combobox string? Most entries in the combobox will be test2010, test2011, test2012, the year part is what I'll requery based on.

Comment: Yes: `Right("test2010", 4)` will give you "2010".  So I think you may want something like `Right(Forms!YourForm!YourCombo, 4)`

Comment: I accepted the answer...although I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong in the SQL code...I guess I need to dig into this a little further. Thanks again.

Comment: OK.  Post a new question which shows us the details of what you're trying now.  Include the text of any error message and tell us which line in the code triggers that error.  If no error message, tell us what you want it to do and what it does instead.  I suspect you may be close to solving this already.  :-)  You can get more eyeballs on your question sooner by tagging it with ms-access instead of ms-access-2010

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible.Just add your stuff to the 'YourComboName.After_Update'.
Look for the Events of the Form that are fired before the form is shown. There build your query as like HansUp suggested.